# Getting the texture scale with assimp

Tags: c++, assimp, wavefront

I'm trying the texture scale from the .mtl file. Opening the file in notepad I can see that it has **map_Kd -s 4.000000 4.000000 1.000000 crate_diffuse.dds**

I am trying thte code below but it returns aiReturnFAILURE.

```
for (UINT j = 0; j < material->GetTextureCount(type); j++) 
{
    aiString str;
    material->GetTexture(type, j, &str);

    aiUVTransform uvTransform;
    if (material->Get(AI_MATKEY_UVTRANSFORM(aiTextureType_DIFFUSE, j), uvTransform) == aiReturn_FAILURE)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed\n";
    }

    texture_diffuse = std::string(str.C_Str());
    std::cout << texture_diffuse << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This will happen when not uvTransform was stored for your material. Without any uvTransform your scaling will be 1.0.